# Why square brackets in URL is not considered in api testing using robotframework?

Tags: python-3.x, api, url, robotframework, web-api-testing

I am trying to api test few APIs using Robot framework.
when I try to test api with square brackets it is not getting considered and getting wrong response. Whereas the same api is able to give correct response in POSTMAN.

I have the below API:
https://orbit.com/s2e/api/q1/client/?filter[customField.ID]=1003

When I hit in Postman I am getting valid response as

```
 "data": {
    "total_count": "1",
    "customer": [
        {
            "id": "123" } ] }
```

The same API 
https://orbit.com/s2e/api/q1/client/?filter[customField.ID]=1003 hit in Robot framework  gives

```
"data": {
    "total_count": "0",
    "customer": [] }
```

Then I saw various encoding and found to use %5B and %5D instead of [ and ] but that API is working properly in postman but in robotframework, it is giving all data i.e filter not working.

https://orbit.com/s2e/api/q1/client/?filter%5BcustomField.ID%5D=1003
Can anyone guide me here?

Comment: @SidaraKEO, Can you provide an example how to convert to base64.? I tried but not working
${relativeurl}=    Evaluate    base64.b64encode($relativeurl)    base64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to encode URL Path by create custom Library for Robotframework.

**For Python V2**

```
import urllib   
def encodeUrlPath(s): 
   return urllib.quote_plus(s)
```

**For Python V3**

```
import urllib.parse
def encodeUrlPath(s): 
  return urllib.parse.quote_plus(s)
```

Comment: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'quote_plus'
GOT THIS error

Comment: are you using python 3 ?

Comment: i have added new answer

Comment: It is encoding now thanks ! for ur answer
but getting error like  Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /
do not know what to do
am accepting ur answer as it encoded
but not working for my url

Comment: @anj the error is because the OS (your DNS actually) cannot resolve the hostname. Looking at the answer, you must probably have passed the full url to the keyword - `https://orbit.com/s2e/etc`, right? If so, then it has url-encoded the reserved characters too - `/`. You need to either pass only the parameters, or this method needs to be redid to be more intelligent.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is not with the square brackets but with the equal sign.
It is difficult to know what problem you are facing as you don't share your Robot Code.

But here are two implementation of basic GETS performed on URL that contain square brackets. Note that I used a backslash (`\`) before the `=` otherwise it is considered as a named argument.

Implementation with [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/):

```
*** Settings ***
Library  requests

*** Test Case ***
mytest
    ${response} =  requests.get  https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1\=[bar1]&foo2\=bar2
    Log To Console  ${response.json()}
```

Implementation with [`RequestsLibrary` library](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests):

```
*** Settings ***
Library  RequestsLibrary

*** Test Case ***
mytest
    Create Session  postman_echo  https://postman-echo.com
    ${response} =  Get Request  postman_echo  /get?foo1\=[bar1]&foo2\=bar2  
    Log To Console  ${response.json()}
```

Comment: Not working getting 0 results only whereas expected is 1 count
url="https://orbit.com/s2e/api/q1/client/?filter%5BcustomField.ID%5D\\=1003" gave double \\ as single was giving error